# Teradata abort session that makes the DBA sleep better at night

Tags: teradata

Since execute on SybLib.AbortSessions allows the grantee to pretty much down the entire server, I wonder if the below might be a more sensible alternative, from the perspective of a dba granting these rights to power-accounts:

```
create macro Dbc.mcAbort ( sess_id number ) 
as
(
  Select SyLib.AbortSessions( '-1', USER, :sess_id, 'Y', 'Y' );
);

grant Dbc.mcAbort to grantee_id;
```

Curious if this could work as designed.

Comment: Depends on what you want, currently it's invalid code (there's no `USERNAME`), changed to `USER` this user can abort his own sessions. If you need more control you can switch to a Stored Procedure to add more checks like *abort SELECTs only*.

Comment: sorry, USERNAME was a typo, meant USER.